# quiero cambiar el placeholder de una etiqueta html usando javascript

Tags: javascript

esta es mi etiqueta html

```
<div class="box">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"size="40" placeholder="nombre">
    </div>
```

aqui el codigo javascript

```
    let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

    if(nombre==null){
        nombre.setAttribute("placeholder", "error")

    }
```

me da este error:
`script.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`

Comment: Estás obteniendo el valor del campo y no el elemento HTML correspondiente. Solo quita el `.value` y compara `if(nombre.value == '')`, con eso ya debe funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Los input por defecto tienen un string vacio, por eso no te funcionaba.

```js
// quita el value 
// ya que el .value retorna un string vacio
// con este código estas retornando el elemento
let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");

    // verifica que el valor del elemento sea un string vacio
    if(nombre.value==''){
        nombre.setAttribute("placeholder", "error")

    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"size="40"       placeholder="nombre">
</div>
```